# Image field gets cleared off in django when i submit it

Tags: python, django, social-media

I am trying to create a social media app similar to Instagram however for some reason when I load the picture into the image field and submit it, the image gets cleared, and says that the field is required.

[Before submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwjKf.png)

[After submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvGPW.png)

In Django, the code for
views.py

```
@login_required
def new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateNewPost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, "Post has been created")
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreateNewPost()
    return render (request, "posts/post_form.html", {"form":form})
```

I have kept the default user to none temporarily as it insisted me to choose one when I created the models initially. Is that the reason for this problem? If so how do I get rid of it.

Html code...

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add a Post!</legend>
            {{ form | crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>                
        </div>
    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=254)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        width, height = img.size
        ratio = width/height
        if img.height > 500:
            outputsize = (500, (height/ratio))
            img.thumbnail(outputsize)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateNewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["image","caption"]
```

and just in case, urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('new_post/', views.new_post, name="new_post"),
]
```

I have also tried using class-based views which gave me the same error

Comment: I have tried the same thing in the django admin interface and this same error comes in as I haven't chosen an author. Is there any possibility to automatically get the current author as an input?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass [**`request.FILES`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form, this is a dictionary-like object that contains the `UploadedFile` objects for the files uploaded:

```
@login_required
def new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateNewPost(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Post has been created')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreateNewPost()
    return render (request, 'posts/post_form.html', {'form':form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: OMG that worked Perfectly!!! Thanks a lot for your help. Means a lot!!